# how to expand an ini-file in perl

Tags: perl, ini

I need to expand an INI-file in perl.
I have a given INI-File that I can read with Config::IniFiles, but I need to add parameters to that INI file too.

For example the file looks like

```
[section1]
param1=val1
param2=val2

[section2]
param1=val3
param2=val4
```

and i need to add params to the sections like

```
[section1]
param1=val1
param2=val2
param3=val5

[section2]
param1=val3
param2=val4
param3=val6
```

I don't know if there is a Module for that in CPAN. Didn't find one until now that would do the Job.
Thank you for any ideas to solve this problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Config::IniFiles` allows to add parameters in sections: see [newval](http://search.cpan.org/~wadg/Config-IniFiles-2.38/IniFiles.pm#newval%28$section,_$parameter,_$value_[,_$value2,_...]%29)

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use Config::IniFiles;
    my $cfg = new Config::IniFiles( -file => "cfg.ini" );

    $cfg->newval("section1", "param3", "val5");
    # add all new values in corresponding sections ...
    $cfg->RewriteConfig;
```

Read also the section [BUGS](http://search.cpan.org/~wadg/Config-IniFiles-2.38/IniFiles.pm#BUGS) for `RewriteConfig`.

Comment: I'll try this and will give a feedback if this worked fine or not